# zooming pictures with wx.image

Tags: python, image, wxpython, zooming

im doing a software that paints over images and save them ( for commenting propose ) .
i used the code below to display image to be drown upon.
the problem is: 

how can i zoom in and out ? . 
or should i use another way to display that image ?



`bitmap=wx.bitmap(path,wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
buffer =wx.EmptyBitmap(500,500,32)

dc = wx.BufferedDC(None, self.buffer)

dc.Clear()

dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,True)`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [dc.SetUserScaling](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6/wx_wxdc.html#wxdcsetuserscale)